# Is there any way how to check if transaction contains incoming ETH?

Tags: ether, ethers.js, parser

I'm using ethers.js library, I have decoded TX, where I see logs, events, etc.

But is there any way how to check that this transaction contains incoming ETH?

When sending ETH, there is .value attribute, but I didn't find a way how to detect that some contract call caused ETH send.

I can detect token send via `transfer` event, or I can detect `withdraw` for WETH->ETH conversion, but I would need some universal way how to get amount of incoming ETH.

Is it possible in any way?

Thanks

Comment: if you don't want to enable traces (because it is going to be dead slow) , you can just dump the `value` to the log at this line : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2a2b0419fb966c54fb86b17bbccea743a45b4d2a/core/vm/evm.go#L168
add something like: `log.Info("value_is","value",value.String(),"contract_addr",addr.String())` (just at the beginning of the function). You will also have to import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/log" package. Then `go build` and run this custom geth node. Parse the log to extract all the data

Comment: same for `StaticCall()` , `DelegateCall()` and all the call variations

Comment: but this only will tell you that some contract at some depth receives eth, not that it is "incoming". To check increase in balances you must trace the state changes

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my contract. I need to call some contracts from the automation script so the only way is probably the slow traces or depends on side-effect events (for example monitor withdraw from WETH if possible, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some RPC node provider, which supports traces, to get so-called "*internal transactions*". For example - [`debug_traceTransaction`](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/debug-tracetransaction) You'll get the internal call tree, and you look there for a `CALL` to the desired `address` with `value > 0`

Comment: Thanks, I found also this solution but as mentioned above, it's a deadly slow. Obviously it would be much faster to write solution based on events if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing built-in. You should write a custom function for that in your smart contract.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it for contract call from the script, not contract. In case of contract it would be much easier in this case.